# How to use pandas for loop iterrows() in python function method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

How to use pandas for loop iterrows() in python function methods , if am calling inside function it was throwing error. "Attribute Error:series object has no iterrows "

i tried with applying lambda as well

am having one dataframe, dataframe has 16 columns cust_id, order_id, value, date, jan, feb, mar, apr, may, june ... upto dec month are the columns will be there

Using group by cust_id & order_id - I have to multiply & add for each current row and previous rows for last 11 month Values columns

If previous month values are not present, that particular month should be considered as 0 like for Ex: In date column first row was starting from 12th[Dec] month so previous months(11) values Nov, Oct, Sep, Aug, Jul, ... are not present in dataframe for that calculation should be 0

```
For Ex:
cust_id  order_id    date     value   output 
 1008      001    2020-02-01   3000    2200   [3000*0.4 +3000*0.0 +2000*0.5+1000*0.0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0]
```

```
Input Dataframe 
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import datetime

    df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id': ['1008'] * 4 + ['1009'] *4,
                    'order_id': ['51'] * 4 + ['192'] * 4,
                    'Date': ["2020-12-01",
                             "2021-01-01",
                            "2021-02-01",
                            "2021-03-01",
                            "2020-12-01",
                            "2021-01-01",
                            "2021-02-01",
                            "2021-03-01"],
                     'month':[12,1,2,3,12,1,2,3],
                     'Value': [1000, 2000, 3000, 3000, 6000, 9000, 180, 400],
                       'Dec': [0.1]*2+ [0]*2 + [0.5]*2 + [0.5]*2,
                      'Jan': [0.1]*2+ [0.5]*2 + [0.3]*2 + [0]*2,
                      'Feb': [0.2]*2+ [0]*2 + [0.1]*2 + [0.5]*2,
                      'Mar': [0.5]*2+ [0.4]*2 + [0.1]*2 + [0.2]*2,
                      'Apr': [0.3]*2+ [0.5]*2 + [0.4]*2 + [0.6]*2,
                      
                      })
```

```
Am calling below like below 
def dataframe_parser(df):
    after_out=[]
    after_out=[]
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        cust = df['cust_id'][index]
        order = df['order_id'][index]
        yearMonth = []
        yearMonth = df["Date"][index]
        splits = yearMonth.split("-")
        month = int(splits[1])
        year = int(splits[0])
        for i in range(11):
            month-=1
            if(month==0):
                month=12
                year-=1
            correctMonth = str(month) if month >=10 else '0'+str(month)
            yearMonth.append(str(year)+"-"+correctMonth+"-01")
        month = df['month'][index]
        weights = []
        for i in range(1,13):
            weightindex = '0'+str(i) if i<10 else str(i)
            weights.append(df[weightindex][index])
        previousMonths = parser(yearMonth)
        cash_array = [0 for i in range(12)]
        for i in range(12):
            previousEntry = df[(df['cust_id']==cust) & (df['order_id']==order) & (df['year_month']==previousMonths[i])]
            if(len(previousEntry)==1):
                cash_array[i] = int(previousEntry['value'])
        cash_array.reverse()
        rotated_array = [0 for i in range(12)]
        for i in range(12):
            rotated_array[(i+month)%12] = cash_array[i]
        rotated_array = np.asarray(rotated_array)
        weights = np.asarray(weights)
        final = np.dot(rotated_array,weights)
        after_out.append(final)
        return after_out

df['out']= df.apply(dataframe_parser)
 & 
df['out']=df.apply(lambda x: dataframe_parser(x),axis=1)
```

````
``` Output Dataframe
data
###
  cust_id   order_id    Date    Value    Output
0   1008    51     2020-12-01   1000      100
1   1008    51    2021-01-01    2000      300
2   1008    51    2021-02-01    3000      1000    
3   1008    51    2021-03-01    3000      2200
4   1009    192   2020-12-01    6000      3000
5   1009    192   2021-01-01    9000      5700
6   1009    192   2021-02-01    180       3090
7   1009    192   2021-03-01    400       3170
````

Comment: Your code would not work on your sample data. Please either update the sample data or the code to match each other. Also if you could explain your desired output that would be helpful too.

Comment: @Nick : I have updated entire logic ,input & expected output as well shown sample calculation as well based on that only whole logic should work..

Comment: @Nick: do you get any chance to resolve ?

Comment: The code you are showing cannot possibly run, as there is no "year_month" column in your sample data. Besides, you are assigning `month` twice. Please provide a *minimal*, *complete*, and *reproducible* example.

Comment: @TurePålsson: forgive i have updated instead of "Date"

Comment: @TurePålsson: Month column am splitting from Date column itself

Comment: @TurePålsson : My overall scenario is to achieve output column by calculation(adding & multiplication) you can check this logic ```For Ex:
cust_id  order_id    date     value   output 
 1008      001    2020-02-01   3000    2200   [3000*0.4 +3000*0.0 +2000*0.5+1000*0.0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0] ```

Answer (score 0):

`df.apply(dataframe_parser)` calls `dataframe_parser` for each column of the dataframe. Thus, inside `dataframe_parser`, `df` is a series (representing a column of the original dataframe).

I have not tried to analyze what you are trying to do, but it might be that you simply want to do `dataframe_parser(df)`.

Comment: Palsson: i just to want to iterate rows inside python method & call that method outside through apply or any other

Comment: If you want to call the function with the dataframe as an argument, then call the function with the dataframe as an argument: `dataframe_parser(df)`.

Comment: Yes i tried same but not working ! can you try or show how to work